# Getting a list out of an extractor -- or even a Match

Tags: regex, scala

First, I was like *cool*...

```
scala> var nameRE = """\W*(\w+)\W+(\w+)\W*""".r
nameRE: scala.util.matching.Regex = \W*(\w+)\W+(\w+)\W*

scala> var nameRE(first, last) = "Will Smith " 
first: String = Will
last: String = Smith
```

Then I was like *darn*...

```
scala> var listOfVowels = "(([aeiou])*)".r
listOfVowels: scala.util.matching.Regex = (([aeiou])*)

scala> var listOfVowels(vowels:List[String]) = "uoiea"
<console>:7: error: scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : List[String]
 required: java.lang.String
       var listOfVowels(vowels:List[String]) = "uoiea"
```

Now I'm like *huh* ...

```
scala> (listOfVowels findFirstMatchIn "uoiea" get) subgroups
res35: List[String] = List(a)
```

[ In case my question isn't obvious: how do I get a list of all the subgroups actually matched by a pattern, ideally in an extractor but in any case without writing a second-level matcher.  The correct answer here would be `List(u, o, i, e, a)` of course. ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will let you extract the pattern:

```
scala> var listOfVowels(vowels @ _*) = "uoiea"
vowels: Seq[String] = List(uoiea, a)
```

However, the pattern doesn't do what you expect it to -- it doesn't generate multiple groups. The regex library rule is one set of parenthesis, one group, and every regex I know works that way.

Comment: Every reqex *api* may work this way, but the underlying libraries certainly support nested groups.  The Scala API might not be alone in not exposing nested groups, but I was getting used to Scala not sucking in areas where most other languages do suck.  Ah, well, the search for perfection continues.

Comment: @Malvolio Ah, well, I'll grant you that. I wished it worked too. Alas, I have a long story of love and hate towards Scala's Regex. It gives a glimpse of paradise but fails to follow through. If I had settled on a good API, I'd have made a replacement library by now.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge it is not possible to convert a subpattern of type (E)* in a regular expression into a List of Strings. This would be because the regular expression mechanism used in Scala is implemented using the JDK's default implementation for regexes (java.util.Pattern, java.util.Matcher, etc.) and this implementation does just not support capturing multiplicities of subpatterns. In case of a match the subpattern (E)* will only capture the last match for that subpattern. To my knowledge, this behavior even holds true for the majority of regex implementations.

Although I believe your case to be a simplified version of your actual problem, a simple solution for the described case does exist :

```
scala> "[aeiou]".r findAllIn "hello, world!" toList
res1: List[String] = List(e, o, o)
```

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit stylistically sloppy.

```
scala> implicit def mkRr(regex: String) = new { def rr = new { def unapply(s: String) = (regex.r findAllIn s toList) match { case Nil => None ; case xs => Some(xs) } } }
mkRr: (regex: String)java.lang.Object{def rr: java.lang.Object{def unapply(s: String): Option[List[String]]}}

scala> val ListOfVowels = "[aeiou]".rr
ListOfVowels: java.lang.Object{def unapply(s: String): Option[List[String]]} = $anon$1$$anon$2@49f2afad

scala> val ListOfVowels(vowels) = "uoiea"
vowels: List[String] = List(u, o, i, e, a)
```